# Calling Javascript from jsp onchange of a dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a list of group and in each group I have a list of members. In `jsp` each group is shown in a row of table and each row contains a `dropdown` of members. Please see the image below -

[image]

What I am trying to do is - if I select a member from the `dropdown` then it's `onchange` trigger a javascript function and the user Id is shown in an alert.(for test purpose I'm now using alert, later I use the userId/member ID for other task).

In the first `dropdown` there are some members - razib, syeful, proshanto. If I select a member from the first `dropdwon` then the member id is shown properly in the alert. But if I select any member from the other `dropdwon` (displaying the member name bulbul and rony) then the `javascript` function is not triggered. Can any one help me what are the problems with the code -

The jsp snippet -

```
<select id="userSelect" name="user">
    <c:forEach items="${group.users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
        <option id="aUser" value="${user.id}"> <c:out value="${user.name}"/> </option>
    </c:forEach>                
</select>
```

And the `javascript` snippet is -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#userSelect').change(function(event) {
        var userId = $("select#userSelect").val();
        alert("User ID :"+userId);
    });//change()               

}); //document.ready()
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** The answer given by [San Krish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790364/san-krish) and [Carsten Løvbo Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943218/carsten-l%C3%B8vbo-andersen) works for a single single id of `<select>`. But I have multiple `<select>` with the id "userSeelct" because this is in a forEach loop. If I use class instead of ID then it is also not working.Please see How the `<select>` actually in my code-

```
<c:forEach id="groupId" var="group" items="${groupListForm.groups}" varStatus="status">
    <select id="userSelect" name="user">
        <c:forEach items="${group.users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
            <option id="aUser" value="${user.id}"> <c:out value="${user.name}"/</option>
        </c:forEach>                
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

The earlier given answer is OK for a single `<select>`. But I think the problem is the `<select>` is also in a for each loop and there are multiple `<select>` with the same id/class. In this case how can I solve the problem? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it as,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userSelect').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried with this but it gives the following error - "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function." Is there any version related issue of jquery?

Comment: Have you added the `jquery` library . wrap your code inside the `.ready(function())` function

Comment: I have already added jquery library and the function is wrapped inside a document.ready(function()). But the <select></select> is under another forEach loop.

Comment: That's not the issue.  You should add the reference of jquery lib before your function

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
$("#userSelect").on("change", function() {
   alert( this.value );
});
```

This should solve your problem!